# How to run multiple update and insert queries after a LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, load-data-infile

We update several tables of our database thanks to CSV files (exported from our ERP)

The problem is that these tables must be able to update several other tables

Let's take a fictitious example, when I make a `LOAD DATA INFILE` of the `all_order` table (containing all the commands), it must directly:

- Update the KPI table `order_kpi`
- Insert in the `order_summary` table, the number of orders recorded by commercial

I wanted to put a trigger on the insert of the table `all_order`, but I think that it executes the trigger for each line of the CSV (more than 15 000 lines ...) and makes me plant my local server

**To note:** It is a PHP script which manages the `LOAD DATA INFILE` (because I need it to be dynamic and that it corresponds to the needs of the user) and I do not wish to put my requests of insertion and update in this PHP script

So my question is:
**How to create a trigger (or other mysql function) that runs after the `LOAD DATA INFILE` is complete ?**

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Do you have a question?

Comment: It is true that it was not clear, I edited my post, thank you

Comment: The short answer is: there is no such functionality in mysql that triggers an event once load data statement completes. The best place to do any post ingestion processing is from the place where you execute your data loading - i.e. your php script. Rationale: the php script knows when the load completes and if there was an error.

Comment: To be honset, you should consider using a bespoke ETL tool as opposed to writing the logic a in php script...